# How to get a DropDown in a TextField in Flutter

Tags: drop-down-menu, flutter

I have an application in Flutter, I would like to add one `TextField` that has a Floating Menu nested inside it, TextField should it serve as a filter in `DropDownButton`, something like [this](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdownfield) , but with the floating menu appearing over the fields, and do not push for down. and one `dropDownButton` that can select nested items. How do I add the `dropDownButton` in `TextField` and search in the nested list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use overlay..

```
void showOverlay(BuildContext context) {
    // in builder write a function that return your dropdown text widgets which are positioned under your textfield
    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: _build);

    Overlay.of(context).insert(overlayEntry);
    // call remove when there is nothing to show
    overlayEntry.remove();
  }
```

And read some information about overlay by google searching.. I guess it'll help you

Comment: Thanks @Daniyar, that worked. But I switched to component `flutter_typeahead`, This worked best.